# How to link post titles on page A to its posts on page B?

Tags: posts, permalinks, pages, links

I set and reversed the order of a list of post titles on my front page with:

```
<?php
global $post;
$args = array( 'category' => 6 );
$myposts = get_posts( $args );
$reverseposts = array_reverse( $myposts, true);
foreach( $reverseposts as $post ) : setup_postdata($post); ?>
<?php the_title(); ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Now I'm not being able to find the proper "a href" line to link those titles to its posts called in another temp file. I hardcoded:

```
<a href="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/category6"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
```

but I guess there's a proper way to get "category6" dynamically.

Any help would be most appreciated.
Thx in advance.

Answer (score 1):

[get_category_link](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_category_link) is what you are looking for. And you could just use:

```
<?php echo get_category_link(6); ?>
```

and that will output the url to the category page.

```
<a href="<?php echo get_category_link(6); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
```

Comment: Thx, weston. I added it to my previous line:                <a href="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/<?php echo get_category_link(6); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a> and it worked. Do u think i could add a page jump straight to where the post is on the page?